# Having recordMyDesktop export audio and video in two different files

Tags: audio, video, arch-linux

As the title dictates. How can I make it output the video in, for example, `rMD_video1.*` and the audio in `rMD_audio1.mp4`?

If it isn't possible, how can I separate these two? I'm sure it's possible somehow, just don't know how...

For those not aware, the output format for recordMyDesktop is `.ogv`.

Thanks for your help once again guys! :)

Comment: Did you mean `.ogv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if RecordMyDesktop can do this (I doubt it, since it's probably not a common need). You can split the file with ffmpeg, though:

```
##  Get the audio:
ffmpeg -i input.ogv -vn -c copy audio.ogg
##  Get the video:
ffmpeg -i input.ogv -an -c copy video.ogv
##  Get both with a single command:
ffmpeg -i input.ogv -vn -c copy audio.ogg -an -c copy video.ogv
```

If you want the audio in an MP4, you'll want to re-encode it to AAC (AAC is the actual audio codec, while MP4 is a 'container' format, which can contain many different video, audio and subtitle streams). See [the AAC encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) on the ffmpeg wiki. That wiki also contains useful guides to video encoding - check out the [x264 guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) if you want to put the video in an MP4.